# Add a link in my code

Tags: c#, razor, visual-studio-2017

I am creating a project for my college work and I wish to add a link. For example:

I am an owner of a shop during day and a coder by night. I have these links opened up of different car companies and I wish to add their links in my own website which should redirect the user to those company's website(s) in listview. This is my code right now:

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Brands";
}

<h2>Brands</h2>
```

I wish to add this link in the code which should be visible on my website page a well.

https://www.renault.co.in/

How should I do it?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1):

You mean something like that?

```
 <a href="https://www.renault.co.in/"><h2>Renault</h2></a>
```

Comment: Yes, yes, yes, thank you very much and a Happy New Year to you.

Comment: Happy New Year to you too.